# compute_class_weight using Dask dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, dask

I got a Dask Dataframe where one of the columns is the actual label. The rest of the columns are features. However, I am unsure about how to set 'X' and 'y' to future train sklearn models and `compute_class_weight` as the dataset is very imbalanced. 
To do so, I have already tried:

```
fn = 'train_text_encoded_08V.parquet'
df_dd = dd.read_parquet(fn)

X = df_dd[df_dd.columns[1:]]
y = df_dd['actual_label'].values


class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced',
                                                 np.unique(y),
                                                 y)

class_weight_dict = dict(enumerate(class_weights))
```

I got the following error:

> ValueError: ('Arrays chunk sizes are unknown: %s', (nan,))

Which I believe it is because:

```
print(y)
out[]: dask.array<values, shape=(nan,), dtype=int64, chunksize=(nan,)>
```

I believe I am not loading X and y in a correct way.. How can I make it?

Answer (score 1):

Dask does not make this type of computations until you explicitly state it. Try

```
X = df_dd[df_dd.columns[1:]].compute()
y = df_dd['actual_label'].compute()
```